# Drop a given number of positive items of a given list

Tags: scala, list, scala-collections

Suppose I need a function `List[Int] => Option[List[Int]]` to drop exactly `n` elements of a given list *if and only if* all of them `> 0`. If the list size `<= n` the function should return `None`.

For instance:

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = ???
val pos4: List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = posn(4)

scala> pos4(Nil)
res18: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> pos4(List(-1))
res19: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> pos4(List(-1, 2, 3))
res20: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> pos4(List(1, 2, 3))
res21: Option[List[Int]] = None

scala> pos4(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
res22: Option[List[Int]] = Some(List(5))

scala> pos4(List(1, 2, 3, -4, 5))
res23: Option[List[Int]] = None
```

I am writing `posn` like that:

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = xs => 
  if (xs.size >= n && xs.take(n).forall(_ > 0)) Some(xs.drop(n)) else None
```

This function seems working bit it doesn't seem elegant and idiomatic. How would you re-write it ?

Comment: This seems like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's probably correct but I prefer keeping all my questions in one place (that happens to be SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an idiomatic or elegant way to do this. There seems to be no generic pattern that can be extracted from your logic, except what you have already done (using `drop` and `take`), so I don't believe you will find some more useful predefined method

However, you are traversing your list a few times, and this could be avoided:

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = xs => {
  val (head, tail) = xs.splitAt(n) //does take and drop in one run
  if (head.lengthCompare(n) == 0 && head.forall(_ > 0)) Some(tail) // lengthCompare does not compute the whole length if there is no need to
  else None 
}
```

This is still not perfect, and more verbose than your version.

You could also do all of it at once, with tail recursion (here assuming `n>=0`):

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = xs =>
  if (n == 0) Some(xs) 
  else if (xs.isEmpty || xs.head <= 0) None
  else posn(n - 1)(xs.tail)
```

This would be more efficient if `List` was naively implemented, but I really doubt you will see any improvement.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `splitAt` ! Forgot about it.

Comment: Thanks for `lengthCompare` too ! Did not know about it.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an (arguably) more idiomatic implementation using Pattern Matching and a recursive call to `posn` - but I'm not sure it's preferable to your suggested implementation:

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = xs => (n, xs) match {
  case (0, _) => Some(xs) // stop if enough objects dropped
  case (_, head :: tail) if head > 0 => posn(n - 1)(tail) // drop positive and move on
  case _ => None // found a negative item or end of xs => "fail"
}
```

Comment: Looks nicer, thanks. I would prefer a non-recursive implementation though.

Comment: @Michael this is tail recursion (it's the same as a while loop). 
It is actually more efficient then yours, because it only makes one pass through the first (at most) n elements, while you make three ...
May I ask, why it is that you "prefer non-recursive implementation"?

Comment: I know about `tail recursion` :) That's just a matter of my personal taste.

Comment: It seems scala fails to see this as tail-recursive (maybe because of the curried call?). You can check this by adding `@annotation.tailrec` above the function definition.

Comment: Correct, this isn't really tail recursive since the result of applying the function by calling `posn(n-1)` isn't the returned value, we then apply it again using `(tail)`. Some refactoring can transform this into a tail-recursive call though

Comment: Oh, thanks. Did not notice it is not tail recursive.

Comment: @TzachZohar yeah ... I was wondering why you wrote it this way rather than `def posn(n: Int, xs: List[Int]): Option[List[Int]]` - that _would_ be tail-recursive. Any particular reason for making it a higher-order function?

Comment: @MIchael "personal taste" - I see :) That's very ... scientific

Answer (score 2):

I would write a generic version and use that to define `posn`:

```
def dropWhen[T](n: Int, p: T => Boolean, l: List[T]): Option[List[T]] = {
    val (f, s) = l.splitAt(n)
    if (f.length >= n && f.forall(p)) { Some(s) } else { None }
}

def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = l => dropWhen(n, (i : Int) => i > 0, l)
```

Note this method scans the prefix of length `n` twice

Answer (score 1):

Another (non-recursive) alternative: use `zipWithIndex` and `dropWhile` to drop the first N positive numbers, and then check `head` to see whether the first remaining item is exactly at position `n`: if it is, we got what we want, otherwise we can return `None`:

```
def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = xs =>
  Some(xs.zipWithIndex.dropWhile { case (v, i) => v > 0 && i < n })
    .find(_.headOption.exists(_._2 == n)) // first index should be n 
    .map(_.map(_._1)) // remove indices
```

Comment: Your simplification won't work for `List(-1,1,1,1,1)`, would it?

Comment: Correct. Removed the comment.

Comment: I would simplify it with `span` like this: `def posn(n: Int): List[Int] => Option[List[Int]] = _.zipWithIndex span {case (x, i) => x > 0 && i < 4} match { case (a, b) if a.size == n => Some(b map (_._1)); case _ => None }`